# How to mock generic class in Angular 2

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, angular, typescript, karma-runner

My classes I want to mock are:

```
class Class<T>{ ... }

@Injectable()
Manager() { ... }
```

I have this :

```
class FakeClass<T> {

constructor(public optionsForConstructor) {
.. do sth mock some methods etc.
}

 class FakeManager {

  public something;

  constructor() {
  public something: any = new FakeManager({
  ..some options not important here .. 
  });
}
```

I want to test in karma using fake classes:

```
fdescribe('A test', () => {

let INTERVAL: number = 5000;

beforeEach(() => {
addProviders([
  SUT,
  {provide: MyClass, useClass: FakeClass<T>},
  {provide: Manager, useClass: FakeMapIncidentController},
]);

});

  fit('Should test something',
inject([MyClass, Manager], (myClass, manager) => {

   let SUT = new SUT(manager); // my SUT constructor needs Manager instance

   expect(true).toBe(true);
}));
```

But unfortunately this do not work. I get:

```
Cannot resolve all parameters for 'MyClass'(?). 
Make sure that all the    parameters are decorated with
Inject or have valid type annotations
and that 'MyClass' is decorated with Injectable. in...
```

What is wrong with it? It seems it should work. When I delete the provide line for MyClass (since it is not an angular Injectable() service), I get provider error. How to resolve this?

Comment: Use `useValue` instead of `useClass`, and assign it an instance of `FakeClass` instead of the class. The error doesn't seem like it has anything to do with generics, but instead the fact that the constructor takes an argument, which should be a provider, which there is none for.